# Onscreen keyboard for Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I checked the obvious places which are in settings for keyboard and also for language because I read that somewhere. This is a Mac Mini from 2011 if that makes a difference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you seen the standard help on this?  https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25242

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard and check the Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar:

[image]

This will alow you to use the keyboard viewer:

[image]

In the Keyboard System preference, click the Input Sources tab to choose alternate languages:

[image]

Click the Plus sign at the bottom:

[image]

Choose your desired languag(es):

[image]

Comment: To actually use an alternative language and to see it in keyboard viewer, you must not only put it on the list in Input Sources, but you must also select it in the menu bar.

Comment: Added more screenshots to show how to to select alternate languages.